# Wrong bytes are sometimes written to disk. Hardware problems?

Tags: c++, hardware, ram, sha256

I have written a UDP based transfer protocol using C++ 11 (VS2013). It's blazing fast - and works great 99,9% of the time.

[image]

But I have observed a few times that the wrong bytes are written to disk (Samsung 250 GB SSD 850 EVO) - or atleast it seems so.

Here's basically what sometime happens when I transfer a 6GB test file:

1. The file is split up into smaller UDP datapackages - 64K in size. (Network layer disassebles and reassembles the UDP datagrams to a larger package).
2. Client sends the datapackage (udp) to the server - the payload is encrypted using AES256 (OpenSSL) and contains data + metadata. The Payload also contains a SHA256 Hash of the entire payload - as an extra integrity check on top up the UDP checksum.
3. Server receives the datapackage, sends an "ACK" package back to the Client and then calculates the SHA256 Hash. The hash is identical to the Clients hash - all is good
4. Server then writes the data of the package to disk (Using fwrite instead of streams due to the huge performance differences). The server only processes one package at a time - and each filepointer has a mutex guard which protects it from being closed by another worker thread that closes filepointers that have been inactive for 10 secs.
5. Client receives UDP "ACK" packages and re-sends packages that have not been acked (meaning they didn't make it). The rate of incoming ACK packages controls the sending speed of the client (aka. congestion control/throtteling). The order of packages received on the server does not matter since each package contains a Position value (where in the file the data should be written).

After the entire file is transferred I do a full SHA256 hash of the 6GB file on both the server and the client, but to my terror I have observed twice the last few days that the hash is **NOT** the same (when making approx 20 test transfers).

After comparing the files in Beyond Compare, I usually find that there is **one or two bits** (in a 6 GB file) that is wrong on the serverside.

See screenshot below:[image]

Server code - invoked after DataPackage hash has been verified

```
void WriteToFile(long long position, unsigned char * data, int lengthOfData){

    boost::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(filePointerMutex);

    //Open if required
    if (filePointer == nullptr){
        _wfopen_s(&filePointer, (U("\\\\?\\") + AbsoluteFilePathAndName).c_str(), L"wb");
    }

    //Seek
    fsetpos(filePointer, &position);

    //Write - not checking the result of the fwrite operation - should I?
    fwrite(data, sizeof(unsigned char), lengthOfData, filePointer);

    //Flush
    fflush(filePointer);

    //A separate worker thread is closing all stale filehandles 
    //(and setting filePointer to NULLPTR). This isn't invoked until 10 secs
    //after the file has been transferred anyways - so shouldn't matter
}
```

So to sum up:

- The char * was correct in memory on the server - otherwise the Servers SHA256 Hash would have failed - right? (a hash collision with sha256 is extremely unlikely).
- Corruption seems to happen when writing to disk. Since there are about 95.000 of these 64k packages written to disk when sending a 6GB file - and it only happens once or twice (when it happens at all) - means that it is a rare phenomenon

**How can this happen? Is my hardware (bad ram/disk) to blame for this?**

**Do I actually need to read from disk after writing, and doing e.g. memcmp in order to be 100% sure that the correct bytes are written to disk?**
(Oh boy - what a performance hit that will be...)

Comment: Tip:  Try the same test on a second/third computer to see if you have hardware problems.

Comment: The most common problems faced by new users are: 1) Hardware problems. 2) Bugs in the compiler. 3) Bugs in the linker. 4) Bugs in the CPU design. 5) Bad CPU design that no sane person would have come up with. 6) Those meddling kids. And 7), but very rarely and why are you even suggesting this, bugs in the user's code.

Comment: @KerrekSB You forgot to blame the OS, most popular version if it is windows ;)

Comment: Run your code through ASAN, MSAN, TSAN, Valgrind and Helgrind. And of course enable and fix all warnings and pedantic errors. And probably decide on the programming language first.

Comment: UDP, what can go wrong.  If you compute the hash on a packet then you are wasting your time, that's the *one* thing you can count on in UDP.  Not the other things you need that are required to make a file transfer with UDP reliable.  Describe in your question what you do about packets that get lost in transfer and what you do about packets not arriving in the expected order.  Note how the latter issue can easily explain what you observed if the data is repetitive.

Comment: You are not checking return values of the file handling functions. Any of the functions can fail, and you won't know about it.

Comment: Are you assuming the packets will arrive in the same order in which you sent them? Mind you, packet reordering is unlikely to account for single-byte errors in a 6GB file unless most of the file is extremely repetitive.

Comment: Did you do the obvious tests? Trying if exactly the same call with exactly the same input and preferably no parallelization results in exactly the same bug?

Comment: In your screen shot, there is actually only a single bit that is different. So while all the other comments are correct, and you should definitely follow the advices, a single-bit error may be plausible. If you blame your hardware, use some other test tools (e.g. simply copy all your files locally, and compare the checksums of these files).

Comment: You could write same data to three files. If only some have errors then it's hardware. If all have the same errors then it's software.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have added more information in the original post now - regd. the UDP part (but I don't think this is part of the problem?).

Comment: @user694733: Will add more error checking and let you know if it makes any difference

Comment: @LightnessRaces: Packages can arrive in any order - this is supported. Each package has a Position (long long) value which tells the server where in the file to write the data.

Comment: @Aziuth: I have a mutex protecting the entire Write method - so it should be safe - but I can easily process the packages in a single thread. Will retest - and let you know if it seems to help.

Comment: @MartinNyholt: Yes - Good eyes!! Only 1 bit out of 48.000.000.000 bits is wrong. Almost impressive.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Now that's an idea that I like!! I am going to try this at once.

Comment: Let us know how the thing with Dialectus went. But to reiterate, there's a reason UDP isn't used for file transfers: it is a best-effort protocol, and any error handling and data corruption will have to be something you check for yourself. Packets are not resent.

Comment: @DrSatan: The transfer protocol which we have built on top of UDP takes care of errorhandling, integrity, encryption. With these things in place, UDP is actually a much better base protocol for file transfer than TCP. When benchmarking against HTTPS - we get 4-10x the speed - especially between large geographical distances with high latency (which really affects TCP)

Every time you watch a Youtube video in Chrome - UDP is now used as the transport layer protocol (Google QUIC) instead of TCP.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQZ-0mXFmk8

Comment: If you are assuming hardware may be the problem, it will be good to test that first. Run a program that makes a copy of the file multiple times and check the hash every time. No need to send it over the wire which will make the test slow. If you are using Unix/Linux, then better to use "cp" command and that will further help you to know if the problem is in hardware, or in  your software. I don't think "cp" command has any bug, so we may start with at least something which is correct :)

Comment: Regarding UDP vs TCP, there is yet one more thing to consider. Once intermediate hops get under load and start to drop packets, TCP is not "fair" with regard to other protocols. The reason for that is the bandwidth throttling mechanics built into TCP. Basically - the used bandwidth for TCP streams is increased until packets get dropped - then reduced somewhat. This implies, that busy nodes will always drop packets. While TCP handles this,, other (UDP based) protocols might not do so well.

Comment: @BitTickler: Bandwidth Throttling is also part of the Protocol. The rate of incoming ACK packages controls the rate at which the client keeps sending packages to the server.

Comment: @Njål: My recommendation of disabling parallelization was not meant to imply that parallelization causes the bug, it was only for the test, to see if the bug is deterministic. Getting rid of parallelization to remove one element that introduces randomness. Speaking of, did you simplify the program for a test? Like letting the server write abcdefg...abcdefg... or something else like that? And as long as there is no bug, slowly introducing more and more of your original programs features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my local pc - it turned out that it was a RAM issue. Found out by running memtest86.

Nevertheless - I modified the code for our software that runs on our production servers - making it read from disk to verify that the correct bytes were in fact written. These servers write about 10TB to disk every day - and after a week of running the new code - the error happened once. The software corrects this by writing and verifying again - but it's still interesting to see that it actually happened.

1 bit out of 560000000000000 bits were written wrong to disk. Amazing.

I will probably run memtest86 on this server later to see if this is also a RAM issue - but I'm not really super concerned about this anymore since file integrity is more or less ensured, and the servers are showing no signs of hardware problems otherwise.

**So - if file integrity is extremely important to you (like it is for us) - then don't trust your hardware 100% and validate reading/writing operations. Anomalies might be an early sign of HW problems.**